# Error in Compiling DLPC3010 DLPC-API in jetson Nano

Tags: api, cmake, cross-compiling, projector

I am trying to compile DLPC Projector APIs in the jetson nano. However, it is throwing an error as in added snapshot.  I came across one solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17574). However it is not being helpful.

DLPC-APS - https://www.ti.com/tool/DLPC-API

```
    ig@ig-desktop:~/Desktop/Texas Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/samples/dlpc654x_samples/build$ cmake ../
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/ig/Desktop/Texas Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/samples/dlpc654x_samples/build

    ig@ig-desktop:~/Desktop/Texas Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/samples/dlpc654x_samples/build$ make
    [  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/libdlpc654x_sample.dir/home/ig/Desktop/Texas_Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/api/dlpc_common.c.o
    cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’
    CMakeFiles/libdlpc654x_sample.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libdlpc654x_sample.dir/home/ig/Desktop/Texas_Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/api/dlpc_common.c.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libdlpc654x_sample.dir/home/ig/Desktop/Texas_Instruments/DLPC-API-1.8/api/dlpc_common.c.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libdlpc654x_sample.dir/all' failed
```

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post an *image* of the error message. Instead, add that error message to the post in **textual** form. About images, see [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on meta.

Comment: Sure @Tsyvarev I have updated code.